# Substitute Anaconda packages with previous installation

Tags: python, anaconda

I recently installed a brand-new Anaconda version; however, I still have an anaconda3 folder from a previous one. **How can I use all the packages contained in the previous installation with the the current one?**

In other words, I would like to transfer the packages file (if it exists) from the previous installation to the new one; hence, avoiding to reinstall all the packages (e.g. Tensorflow, Keras etc.)

Comment: Here's a hack which you can use -> From the `anaconda/envs` folder, copy the directory of your enviroment which you would like to use. Paste this directory in the new Anaconda installation directory, also in the same `envs` folder. After this you can find a `.conda` directory which stores various conda configurations. This directory will consist of the text file which contains the names of the enviroments present on your machine. Enter the filepath of your env which you just copied into the text file.

Comment: It seems like the old envs folder is empty